# C# DataGridView Column.MinimumWidth with DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader only works in design mode

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is there a way to have my DataGridView honor the `Column.MinimumWidth` value with `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader` at runtime?  It works fine in the designer. However, when I run the WinForms app, the `Column.MinimumWidth` gets permanently reset to `5` and the column is squashed until it contains data.

The designer displays the DataGridView properly with the following is the designer.cs code.

```cs
this.Column8.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
this.Column8.DataPropertyName = "LineNumber";
this.Column8.HeaderText = "Line#";
this.Column8.MinimumWidth = 50;
this.Column8.Name = "Column8";
this.Column8.Width = 50;
```

When the app is run, before adding data, the MinimumWidth and Width properties are reset to `5` and the following code does not do anything:

```cs
this.Column8.MinimumWidth = 50;
this.Column8.Width = 50;
```

I can mostly work around this behavior using the `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells` mode. However, it would be nice if the Visual Studio Designer and runtime experience displays WYSIWYG.

Platform = Visual Studio 2019, update 16.5.5, Windows 10, .NET 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set the AutoSizeMode after setting the width in your code? Like this:

```
this.Column8.MinimumWidth = 50;
this.Column8.Width = 50;
this.Column8.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
```